# Faster way then VMGuestFile Copy?

Tags: vmware-esx

VMGuestFile Copy copies files at approx. 1 MB/s at my environment. It's very slow and it takes ages to move GB's of data.

Is there a better way to copy files faster than with VMGuestFileCopy? Or, is it possible to speed up things somehow?

I don't want to connect the Ethernet adapters. I need a virtual environment solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just setup 'regular' shares either inside or outside the VM (i.e. an NFS or CIFs share) and use that?